# jQuery Insert .after() is inserting as a string not HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my element selected like so

```js
let btn = $("a[translate='server.ipmi.kvm.LAUNCH']")[0];
```

Then when attempting to insert after it i'm doing the following

```js
btn.after('<a class="btn btn-default" onclick="launchNewKvm()">New KVM</a>')
```

This is inserting the content as a string for some reason and not as a button as I'd like, If I wrap this as a jQuery element then it inserts as `[object Object]`

any ideas at all would be appreciated

[Inspect Element after running the .after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3wCZ.png)

Comment: Why the `[0]` ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the standard jQuery library, and not something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you use [`after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after) method of javascript, not `jquery`, which if you need to insert an HTML, it should be a DOM [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) or it will be treated as `text`.

If you want to use `jquery` [`after`](https://api.jquery.com/after/) method, then don't get the `index`

```
let btn = $("a[translate='server.ipmi.kvm.LAUNCH']");

btn.after('<a class="btn btn-default" onclick="launchNewKvm()">New KVM</a>')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my stupidity, I don't use jQuery ever anymore so this threw me when i originally console.log the btn var it would return as an array, so assuming that it was all that matched, i'd want the first one... This worked immediately...

Comment: @Dectom than use `NCH']").first();` or `NCH']").eq(0);` Google is full of solutions.